# Hibernate - persist automatically each relation

Tags: java, hibernate

Maybe it is a simple question, but I can't find out this situation of relations in Hibernate.

I have these Entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<Conversation> posts = new HashSet<Conversation>();
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Conversation { 
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation")
  private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Message { ... }
```

and then I want create User with Conversation and Message at once. Idea should be like this:

```
User user = new User();
     user.getPosts().add(new Conversation(){
        {
            getMessages().add(new Message());
        }
     });

session.persist(user);
```

But just User is saved in database - why isn't it all? Because of default LAZY fetching? Could my idea be implemented somehow?

PS: Of course I know about the solution of persisting each of the entities, but I am used to do like this in other frameworks like nette or Django, so I can't get out of my head.

PPS: I found out that problem is in default CascadeType. Could it be set on globally, e.g. in Hibernate config XML? Is it a good idea (by performance point of view - it is persisted each time on "superpersist" or only in case of changes)?

PPPS: I also found out (opposite to Django) that I have to set FK ex-post for each item added to collection. It is natural (because of selected pure Set type), but new for me. Which approach would you recommend me? Required FK as argument in constructor on item Entity e.g.:

```
  Class Message{
    Message(Conversation conversation){
       setConversation(conversation);
    }
    ...
  }
```

or make a method for adding where FK sets inside e.g.:

```
  Class Conversation{
    ...
    public void addMessage(Message msg){
       msg.setConversation(this);
       getMessages().add(msg);
    }
    ...
  }
```

?

Making Session + configure XML.

```
private final static String CFG = "hibernate-cfg.xml";
    private final static String SCRIPT_FILE = "query.sql";

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static ServiceRegistry buildRegistry() {
        return new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure(CFG)
                .build();
    }

    private static Metadata getMetaData() {
        return new MetadataSources(buildRegistry()).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        return getMetaData().getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        try {
            return getSessionFactory().openSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and the hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learnme
        </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"/>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        </property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>
    <!-- Display all generated SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="learnme.hibernate.entities.User"/>
    <mapping class="learnme.hibernate.entities.Conversation"/> 
    <mapping class="learnme.hibernate.entities.Message"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/cascading.html) and [this](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store#Global_Cascading_Persist_)
you need to have this in your `persistence.xml` file to set it globally:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
   <persistence-unit-metadata>
     <persistence-unit-defaults>
       <cascade-persist/>
     </persistence-unit-defaults>
   </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

> The mapping file has to be located either in the default location,
>   META-INF/orm.xml, or in another location that is specified explicitly
>   in the persistence unit definition (in persistence.xml).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Where this snippet should be placed? In persistance.xml or orm.xml - but these are related to JPA and EntityManager, aren't they? I am using Hibernate config + SessionFactory, is it possobile to integrated it somehow?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're asking. Did you try to follow the links and to implement the suggested approach?

Comment: I added code with session generator. The thing is, that I am not using JPA persistence.xml, but hibernate-cfg.xml, that is different. So, how can I integrate your recommendation in attached links?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to add persistence.xml along with hibernate-cfg.xml? Also you can try adding something like  <property name="cascade">persist</property>

Comment: I tried both ways without effect. In the end, I solved reference on orm.xml in persistance.xml -> it has to be in particular META-INF folder and it is not the default one which Netbeans created <-.

Anyway after that pit it has still no effect. So I decided to make CascadeType annotation to each ManyToSomething relation.

But I would like to ask you for another pain. It is the PPPS in "main" question. I looked around and Hibernate should provides this "filled" FKs in DB. New thread is there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457119/hibernate-mapping-collections-with-auto-fk)