# Hibernate - mapping collections with auto FK

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with ManyToSomething relations. I can't make an annotation that generates properly FKs. Maybe it is whole idea bad (e.g. persisting just one Entity with cascading).

Let's have this simplified code somewhere in program:

```
    Conversation conversation = new Conversation(){{
        getMessages().add(new Message());
    }};

    session.persist(conversation);

    // OR LIKE THIS:

    Message message = new Message();     
    Conversation conversation = new Conversation();

    message.setConversation(conversation);

    session.persist(message);
```

And then simplified Hibernate annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Message{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Conversation conversation;

}

@Entity
public class Conversation{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();

  public Set<Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
  }
}
```

So, the FK for Conversation should be kept in Message (One Conversation - Many Messages). But when the Java code runs, database writes only new ids, without FK on Conversation side. How is it possible?

UPDATE 1 (still no luck):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversation_message")
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Conversation conversation;

... (other fields + getters/setters without annotation)
}

@Entity
public class Conversation{ 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();

... (other fields + getters/setters without annotation)
}
```

UPDATE 2 (with UPDATE 1 Annotation), on this:

```
Conversation conversation = new Conversation();
conversation.getMessages().add(new Message(){{
    setConversation(conversation);
    setText("test");
}});

session.persist(conversation);
```

Hibernate log:

```
insert 
        into
            conversation
            (course_id, created, name, replies, user_id) 
        values
            (null, null, null, true, null)

insert 
        into
            conversation_message
            (file, sent, text) // There is missing conversation_id at all
        values
            (null, null, "Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `Id` field in your code...
What you probably missing is this in both:

```
private Integer id;  

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Then it will be generated automatically on persisting.

UPDATE:
Also to have the foreign key in the table `Messages` you need this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Conversation conversation;
```

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: I tried (updated code above), without results - still no filled FK in DB.

Comment: Turn on logging of queries in Hibernate and look at them

Comment: I turned logging on but it is not helpfull either. I updated model as you said and FK conversation_id is missing in query! I supposed it is due to insertable=false on Conversation.messages, because if I change this attribute to true, I get query with FK -> INTO  conversation_message (conversation_id,... ) VALUES ((int)conversation.id, ...) <- But still it is not the behavior what I am looking for - I need it without additional method setFK(...).